# Rails ActiveRecord sets object attribute nil when creating or initializing object even when value is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When creating a model object active record sets the objects attribute to nil even if the values are set

```
@company.payment_orders.create(subscription_id: 1, price: 1000.0)
#<PaymentOrder id: nil, company_id: 1, subscription_id: nil, price: nil,..>
```

my models look some thing like this

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription
end

class PaymentOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :subscription
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payment_orders
end
```

And class for recording the payment_order

```
class PaymentOrderRecorder
  def initialize(company, subscription, price)
    @company = company
    @subscription = subscription
    @price = price
  end

  def record
    @company.payment_orders.create(subscription_id: @subscription_id, price: @price)
  end
  ....
end
```

Comment: you don't have a relation,   `has_many :payment_orders` in the company. Please add that and try

Comment: yep i have added that relation too. doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a relation, has_many :payment_orders in the company. Please add that and try

Models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription
  has_many :payment_orders
end

class PaymentOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :subscription
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payment_orders
end
```

Then,

```
class PaymentOrderRecorder
  .....

  def record
    @company.payment_orders.create(subscription_id: @subscription_id, amount: @price)
  end
  ....
end
```

Comment: yes i have already tried but doesnt work even the price attribute is set as nil

Comment: price attribute is of type 'float'

Comment: `@variable = @company.payment_orders.create(subscription_id: 1, price: 1000.0),
@variable.errors`, check if any errors are present?

Comment: `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000008872208
 @base=#<PaymentOrder id: 2, company_id: nil, subscription_id: 1, created_at: "2016-10-19 08:15:52", updated_at: "2016-10-19 08:15:52", amount: 0.0>,
 @messages={}>`

Comment: you have taken wrong field name, take `amount` instead ofprice
`@company.payment_orders.create(subscription_id: @subscription_id, amount: @price)`

Comment: no actual i changed the price field to amount and added default 0.0 value. the amount value is still doesnt change it remains default 0.0 event if i assign any other float value like '10.0' or '100.0'

Comment: have you changed it to amount from price? , if yes, paste the insert query once,

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use has_many through association for this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payment_orders
  has_many :subscription,  :through => :payment_orders
end


class PaymentOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :subscription
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payment_orders
  has_many :companies,  :through => :payment_orders
end
```

then perform this query:

```
@company.payment_orders.create(subscription_id: 1, price: 1000.0)
```

it will work